# Geforce experience on linux?

Tags: wine

My question is there are ways to install Geforce experience on linux?
If not,how to install it on wine?
The first "launch" something was loaded but then took off and now will not start.
I need GeForce exp to fix minecraft bug.

Comment: What is Geforce experience?

Comment: years ago it was difficult to install Nvidia drivers on Ubuntu however today its extremely easy ... Settings -> Software & Updates ->  Additional Drivers -> ... give it a few  seconds to warm up ... -> pick lastest Nvidia driver from list  ... Done !!! no need for GeForce Experience

Answer (score 1):

According to the [System Requirements](http://www.nvidia.in/object/geforce-experience-system-requirements-in.html) GeForce Experience is a Windows only program and according to the [Wine App Database](https://www.winehq.org/search?q=%22Geforce+Experience%22) no one has yet tried or tested it under Wine and reported the result. If you feel that you must use Geforce Experience at this point it appears that your best bet would be to [dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6317/how-can-i-install-windows-after-ive-installed-ubuntu) a version of Windows that the program supports.